# zoom to user location not zooming on initial loading after allowing access to to location

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

on initial loading when the app asks for permission for access to your location while using app/ always/ never. once you select an option, the zoom to the user's location doesn't zoom, but if i go back a screen and then come back to the map it does zoom to the user's location. how can i get it to zoom once i select a permission?

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    // Check for Location Services
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    //Zoom to user location
    if let userLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: userLocation, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
        map.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //This will pull the info for where to put annotation
    let annotatedPlace = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotatedPlace.title = annoTitle
    annotatedPlace.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinanteLat, longitude: coordinanteLong)
    map.addAnnotation(annotatedPlace)

    locationAuthStatus()

}

func locationAuthStatus() {
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        map.showsUserLocation = true
    } else {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` so you can respond when you are granted authorization.